# Filtrar valor vazio ou nulo em arquivo JSP usando SQL

Tags: sql, jsp

Boa tarde, tenho uma consulta SQL conforme código abaixo onde tenho 3 filtros, esses filtros uso a clausula where, and e and mas caso um dos filtros esteja em branco o valor retornado também fica em branco.

Como posso fazer esse tratamento, seja no Banco de dados ou diretamente no arquivo JSP?

```
SELECT DISTINCT DECODE (initcap(PP.OVERALL_HEALTH), '', '/itg/images/statusreport/NA.gif', '/itg/images/statusreport/'   || DECODE(UPPER(PP.OVERALL_HEALTH), 'GREEN', 'Verde', initcap(PP.OVERALL_HEALTH))   || '.gif' ) SAUDE_PROGRAMA_ICONE, PP.CONTAINER_NAME NOME_PROGRAMA, HD.VISIBLE_PARAMETER1 TIPO_CLIENTE, HD.VISIBLE_PARAMETER32 DIRETOR, P.NAME
FROM PGM_PROGRAMS PP
INNER JOIN KCRT_REQ_HEADER_DETAILS HD ON HD.REQUEST_ID = PP.PGM_REQUEST_ID
INNER JOIN KCRT_FG_PFM_PROGRAM FP ON FP.REQUEST_ID = PP.PGM_REQUEST_ID
INNER JOIN FM_FINANCIAL_SUMMARY FS ON PP.FINANCIAL_SUMMARY_ID = FS.FINANCIAL_SUMMARY_ID
INNER JOIN PFM_PORTFOLIO_CONTENTS PC ON FS.FINANCIAL_SUMMARY_ID = PC.FINANCIAL_SUMMARY_ID
INNER JOIN PFM_PORTFOLIOS P ON PC.PORTFOLIO_ID = P.PORTFOLIO_ID
WHERE HD.PARAMETER1 = 'CORPORATIVO'
AND HD.PARAMETER32 IN '100427' 
AND P.NAME IN (select p.name as portfolio from pfm_portfolios p
start with p.portfolio_id in '34006' 
connect by prior p.portfolio_id = p.parent_portfolio_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar um `OR` em conjunto com o `AND`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tabela t
 WHERE (:condicao1 = '' OR t.condicao1 = :condicao1)
   AND (:condicao2 = '' OR t.condicao2 = :condicao2)
```

Só não esqueça de isolar as condições com parênteses para ter o comportamento conforme o que foi explicado

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas se eu testei de forma correta ele não supre minha necessidade pois precisa trazer exatamente só o que está no filtro e assim ele traz como se fosse um OR, então acaba não filtrando, embora resolva o problema do valor retornar vazio.

Comment: @GuilhermeMontagnani se você colocar os parenteses no lugar certo certamente irá filtrar. Esse comportamento que você descreveu só ocorre se os parênteses estiverem no lugar errado ou se você não utilizar `AND` entre os parâmetros

Comment: A expressão ficou da seguinte forma: WHERE (HD.PARAMETER1 = 'CORPORATIVO' AND HD.PARAMETER1 = HD.PARAMETER1)
AND (HD.PARAMETER32 = '100427' OR HD.PARAMETER32 is = HD.PARAMETER32)

Comment: @GuilhermeMontagnani você aplicou errado o que eu respondi. Ficaria algo assim: `WHERE (:PARAMETER1 = '' OR HD.PARAMETER1 = :PARAMETER1) AND (:PARAMETER32 = '' OR :PARAMETER32 = HD.PARAMETER32)`

Comment: Entendi, agora não consigo fazer o teste, mas vou salvar a consulta e assim que possível respondo se resolveu meu problema. Agradeço desde já pela ajuda!

Comment: Boa tarde brother, agradeço pela ajuda, mas realmente não funcionou, a consulta retorna vazia.